# Facebook Open Graph Action coding error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, action, facebook-opengraph

i've been figuring it out for ages, there's no problem debugging tool or in the terminal console, but it keeps popping "error occurred" in the following codes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function postCook()
    {
        $pageURL = window.location;

        FB.api('/me/bgfapp:watch?movie=' + $pageURL,'post',
                    function(response) {
            if (!response || response.error) {
                    alert('Error Occurred');
            } else {
                alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
                }
        });
    }
 </script>
```

i tried to echo $pageURL and it returns the current URL successfully, so i can't figure out what's wrong with the above code

---

updated: 30-Jan-2012

the error says: Error Occurred[object Object][object Object]

Comment: print out response. what does this return: alert('Error Occurred' + response + " " + response.error)

Comment: hi, the error says: Error Occurred[object Object][object Object]

Comment: hi, i slightly modify the alert to:
alert('Error Occurred' + response.responseText + " " + response.error.responseText); and the message becomes: Error Occurred undefined undefined

Comment: what does response.error say?

Answer (score 1):

You've probably already found a solution but hopefully this will help someone else.

The problem here is that you don't know the names of the child nodes within the response object. If you can't name the specific node then you're going to continually get that error message: "Error occured [Object object] message"

I have a simple workaround that will allow you to see the error message without knowing the names of the response object's child nodes. JSON.stringify will simply convert the entire object into a string, allowing you to view its contents. It won't be pretty but you'll definitely be able to see the error message in there.

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function postCook()
{
    $pageURL = window.location;
    FB.api('/me/bgfapp:watch?movie=' + $pageURL,'post', function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
          alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        } 
        else {
          alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
        }
    });
}
```

An alternate solution would be to output the contents of the response object to the console rather than executing an alert, just replace line 7 in my code sample with this:

```
console.log(response);
```

From here, you can open the development console of your web browser and traverse the contents of the response object. Since the console is not always available (phonegap apps for example), the former solution is sometimes more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your new error message it looks like you need to see what `response.error` says. Your logic says that either you got no response at all or you got a `response.error`. You should first figure out what case you are in and act accordingly.

`response.responseText` and `response.error.responseText` are undefined because they aren't returned to you.

```
    $pageURL = '/me/bgfapp:watch?movie=' + window.location;

    FB.api($pageURL,'post',
                function(response) {
                     if (!response) { 
                          alert('Error Occurred I got no response with ' + $pageURL);
                     }
                     else if (response.error) {
                          alert('Error Occurred '+ response.error);
                     } else {
                         alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
                     }
             });
```

My suggestion is try simple and work your way up. Debug all variables that you are checking. If you aren't getting a response it could be that your API endpoint call doesn't exist. If you are getting an error then your call is wrong or maybe not authenticated.